# Does geolocation obtained from an IP Address change from time to time?

Tags: ip-address

I am using ipstack api to get geolocation from an IP address. To reduce the number of request to ipstack I planned to store the location in a database. So, if a request comes, I get the IP address, check if there's any record of location of that IP address, if yes then I use that record.

example:

> request from 64.64.4.5 comes >> Check db for location of 64.64.4.5 >> If
> present, then use the location, if not, get location with ipstack.

The problem is, the above solution works if 64.64.4.5 is always in Los Angeles. I don't care if the same client is using this IP Address, as long as this address is always in Los Angeles then its fine.

So, does geolocation obtained from an IP Address change from time to time?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Xfinity did some major work in my neighborhood (in Denver) yesterday...now my IP number geolocates to Massachusetts.